# Using less with twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, bootswatch

I'm trying to use one of the styles from http://bootswatch.com/. I would like to apply the .less version of their styles to bootstrap.css. To do so I'm doing the following as described in http://lesscss.org/#usage:

```
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="variables.less" rel="stylesheet/less">
<link href="bootswatch.less" rel="stylesheet/less">
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But it doesn't work, i.e. I still have the default bootstrap theme.

To simplify I've merged `variables.less` into `bootswatch.less`, so the code now looks like this:

```
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="bootswatch.less" rel="stylesheet/less">
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But still I get the default bootstrap theme.

I've checked with the debugger and all files are properly linked, so I guess I'm doing something wrong in the usage.

Comment: On http://lesscss.org/#usage the attribute `type="text/css"` is kept on the less links also.

Comment: I've added it but still no results!

Comment: out of curiosity, why not compile the less into css?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the less files from bootswatch, I think you also need to use the less files from bootstrap. The `variables.less` file will overwrite the values from the original file.

What I did to make it work is download the bootstrap less files, copy the `bootswatch.less` and `variables.less` to the same folder (I renamed to `variables-bootswatch.less` for forward-compatibility, if bootswatch is not up to date).

Then I modified the `bootstrap.less` file to include those aforementioned files :

```
// Header and everything before variables.less

@import "variables.less"; // Modify this for custom colors, font-sizes, etc
@import "variables-bootswatch.less";

// everything else, then at the end

@import "bootswatch.less";
```

Lastly, you just need to import this file (no CSS)

```
<link href="bootstrap.less" rel="stylesheet/less">
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

It appears that there is one project on github that is meant to build you swatch themes : [swatchmaker on github](https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch/tree/master/swatchmaker). It should produce the appropriate CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the order of script file as follows

```
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="bootswatch.less" rel="stylesheet/less">
```

Comment: "Make sure you include your stylesheets before the script." From http://lesscss.org/#usage